# Restore recordstore after exit application

Tags: java-me, lwuit, midlet, rms, lwuit-list

I have written a LWUIT application that involves two RecordStores  recordStore

and

recordStore2 .

Two methods method  getRecordData  for retriving all records of

recordStore,  method getRecordData2 for retriving all records of

recordStore2 .

two Radiobuttons  rb and rb2  are added  ButtonGroup called group

A TextField called  tf

addition button for adding  a record for either recordstore or recordstore2

after rb  or rb2 is selected

a text which must  written into tf TextField as a record

Two lists  mylist  and mylist2

mylist  to display  all records  of recordstore

mylist2  to display  all records of  recordstore2

All button  to  display  all records of recordstore and recordstore2

Simple problem faces me:-

After  I exit   from   the  application  return back to it and press All button

mylist  and  mylist2 are  null (No record displayed)!

Can anyone thankfully helps me

```
    import java.util.*;

    import com.sun.lwuit.table.*;

    import com.sun.lwuit.table.DefaultTableModel;

    import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

    import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

    import javax.microedition.rms.RecordStore;

    import javax.microedition.rms.RecordStoreNotOpenException;

    import javax.microedition.rms .*;

    import com.sun.lwuit.layouts.*;

    import com.sun.lwuit.*;

    import javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas;


    import com.sun.lwuit.events.*;

    import com.sun.lwuit.plaf.*;

    import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

    import com.sun.lwuit.geom.*;

    import com.sun.lwuit.*;

    import com.sun.lwuit.events.*;

    public class HelloLWUITMidlet3 extends MIDlet implements   Runnable, ActionListener

         {

         private RecordStore recordStore,recordStore2;


           String team,team2;

     public String [] getRecordData()

        {

        String[] str = null;

        int counter = 0;

        try

        {

            RecordEnumeration enumeration = recordStore.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);

            str = new String[recordStore.getNumRecords()];

            while(enumeration.hasNextElement())

                {

                try

                {

                    str[counter] = (new String(enumeration.nextRecord()));

                   counter ++;

                  }

                   catch (Exception e)

                    {

                      e.printStackTrace();

                      }
                            }
                                } 

              catch (Exception e) 

                                   {

                       e.printStackTrace();

                           }


                            return str;
    }

     public String [] getRecordData2()

          {

        String[] str = null;

        int counter = 0;

        try

        {

            RecordEnumeration enumeration = recordStore2.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);

            str = new String[recordStore2.getNumRecords()];

            while(enumeration.hasNextElement())

            {
                try

                {
                    str[counter] = (new String(enumeration.nextRecord()));

                    counter ++;
                }

                catch (Exception e)

                {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        } 

        catch (Exception e) 

                {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return str;

    }

        public void startApp()


        {

          com.sun.lwuit.Display.init(this);


    int bgColor =0x0066CC;

    final ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

    final  RadioButton rb = new RadioButton("First Team");

    final  RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton("Second Team");

    group.add(rb);

    group.add(rb2);


    final  f1 g = new f1();

     final com.sun.lwuit.List mylist =  new com.sun.lwuit.List();

    final com.sun.lwuit.List mylist2 =  new com.sun.lwuit.List();


    final form6 my = new form6();

     final  com.sun.lwuit.Form f = new com.sun.lwuit.Form("Football");

       f.getStyle().setBgColor(0X99CCFF);

      BoxLayout boxlayout =new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);


       final  Button goals = new Button("See goals");

       final  Button button = new Button("Goals Record");

      final    com.sun.lwuit.TextField tf =new com.sun.lwuit.TextField();



     final    com.sun.lwuit.TextField  txtfield5 =new com.sun.lwuit.TextField();


      final    com.sun.lwuit.TextField  txtfield6 =new com.sun.lwuit.TextField();



    final Button addition = new Button("Add Goals");

    final Button All = new Button("All Goals");

    addition.getStyle().setBgColor(0X0066CC);

       com.sun.lwuit.Command back = new com.sun.lwuit.Command("Main_Screen");

    final form6 ff = new form6();

      button.getStyle().setBgColor(0X0066CC);

    goals.getStyle().setBgColor(0X0066CC);

      All.getStyle().setBgColor(0X0066CC);
    Style g_style5 = g.getSelectedStyle() ;

    f.addComponent(button);

    ff.addCommand(back);

     //g.addComponent(main_screen);
    g.addComponent(tf);
    g.addComponent(addition);
     g.addComponent(rb);
     g.addComponent(rb2);


    g.addComponent(All);

     g.getStyle().setBgColor(0X99CCFF);

    g.addCommand(back);

     g.addCommandListener(new ActionListener()

     {


      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {



    f.show();
         }



     }
              );


       ff.addCommandListener(new ActionListener()

     {


      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {



    f.show();
         }



     }
              );

    ff.getStyle().setBgColor(0X99CCFF);





     try{
             recordStore2 = RecordStore.openRecordStore("My Record Store2", true);
            }
      catch(Exception ex)
         { }
     try
     {
             recordStore = RecordStore.openRecordStore("My Record Store", true);
            }
         catch(Exception ex)
         { }

          All.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    try

    {
        com.sun.lwuit.Label l = new com.sun.lwuit.Label("First Team Goals") ;

       ff.addComponent(l);

       String [] record=  getRecordData();

    int j1;

    String valueToBeInserted2="";


    for( j1=0;j1< getRecordData().length;j1++)

      {


    valueToBeInserted2=valueToBeInserted2 + " " + record[j1];


    if(j1==getRecordData().length)

      {

   mylist.addItem(record[j1]);

      }



    }


    ff.addComponent(mylist);

     com.sun.lwuit.Label ll = new com.sun.lwuit.Label("Second Team Goals") ;

      ff.addComponent(ll);


       String [] record2=  getRecordData2();

    int j2;

    String valueToBeInserted="";


  for( j1=0;j1< getRecordData().length;j1++)

  {


valueToBeInserted2=valueToBeInserted2 + " " + record[j1];


if(j1==getRecordData().length)

                {

        mylist.addItem(record[j1]);



             }

             }


    ff.addComponent(mylist2);

          }
    catch(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException e)


         {

         }

    finally

         {
    ff.show();

          }
             }



      }

    );

     button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {


    g.show();

         }


          }

             );

    goals.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

        {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {



         }

      }
    );





    final  Thread th = new Thread(this);







    addition.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

    {


      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    String s =tf.getText();

    if(rb.isSelected())

    {



    if(s!=null && s.length() > 0)

    {

     try{

          String kk =tf.getText();

          mylist.addItem(kk);


                 byte bytestream[] = kk.getBytes()  ;

                 int i = recordStore.addRecord(bytestream, 0, bytestream.length);

         }

     catch(Exception ex) 

                 { }


    Dialog validDialog = new Dialog(" ");


    Style Dialogstyle = validDialog.getSelectedStyle() ;

            validDialog.setScrollable(false);


     validDialog.getDialogStyle().setBgColor(0x0066CC);

            validDialog.setTimeout(1000); 

            TextArea textArea = new TextArea("...."); 


            textArea.setFocusable(false);

           textArea.setText("A new goal has been added"+"" );

            validDialog.addComponent(textArea);


            validDialog.show(0, 10, 10, 10, true);




    }

          }


     else if (rb2.isSelected())
    {


    if(s!=null && s.length() > 0)

    {

     try{

          String kk =tf.getText();


          mylist2.addItem(kk);



           byte bytestream[] = kk.getBytes()  ;

             int i = recordStore2.addRecord(bytestream, 0, bytestream.length);

         }

     catch(Exception ex) { }


    Dialog validDialog = new Dialog(" ");

    Style Dialogstyle = validDialog.getSelectedStyle() ;

            validDialog.setScrollable(false);

     validDialog.getDialogStyle().setBgColor(0x0066CC);

            validDialog.setTimeout(1000); 

            TextArea textArea = new TextArea("....");  

            textArea.setFocusable(false);

           textArea.setText("A new Goal has been added"+"" );

            validDialog.addComponent(textArea);

            validDialog.show(0, 10, 10, 10, true);



    }

          }

    else if((rb.isSelected()==false&&rb.isSelected()==false)||(s==null && s.length()<= 0))

    {

        Dialog validDialo = new Dialog(" ");


            validDialo.setScrollable(false);


    validDialo.getDialogStyle().setBgColor(0x0066CC);


            validDialo.setTimeout(5000);  


            TextArea textArea = new TextArea("....");  


            textArea.setFocusable(false);


           textArea.setText("please enter scorer name and choose his team");


            validDialo.addComponent(textArea);





            validDialo.show(50, 50, 50, 50, true);


            txtfield6.clear();


     }



        }

    }

    );





          f.show();



        }

    public void run ()

          {

       while(true)

         {


            String get[] = getRecordData();


             Dialog validDialog = new Dialog(" ");


             Style Dialogstyle = validDialog.getSelectedStyle() ;


            validDialog.setTimeout(5000);


            validDialog.setScrollable(true);



            validDialog.setLayout(null);


            validDialog.setTimeout(5000);

             TextArea textArea = new TextArea( );


    for(int ii=0;ii<getRecordData().length;ii++ )



    {


            textArea.setColumns(getRecordData().length);


            validDialog.addComponent(textArea);



            validDialog.show(10, 10, 10, 10, true);



               System.out.println(get[ii]+"\n");


             System.out.println(textArea.getColumns()+"\n");


                      }


                            }


                                }
        public void pauseApp()


                          {

                           }

        public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional)

                                           { 

                                           }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 

          {


           notifyDestroyed();

           }

         public  class f1 extends   com.sun.lwuit.Form


      {

            com.sun.lwuit.TextField tf;


               public f1()


              {


      com.sun.lwuit.Form f1 = new com.sun.lwuit.Form("Goals Records");


        tf =new com.sun.lwuit.TextField();


              }






        }



    public  class form6   extends   com.sun.lwuit.Form


      {

    com.sun.lwuit.TextField txtfield3;

    com.sun.lwuit.TextField tf3;


       public form6()

              {

      com.sun.lwuit.Form mylist = new com.sun.lwuit.Form("Goals List");


              }




    }

}
```

Comment: Please format this code (and description).  It's unreadable as is.  Thanks.

Comment: I have formatted the code , can you help me  plz?

Comment: @AliPour Is it couldn't retrieve rms records in a form list of after exit from app

Comment: you can retrived rms records even exit from app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should first open recordStore and than read it's contents.
in getRecordData() method you should first open record store and than use

```
RecordEnumeration enumeration = recordStore.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);
```

modify method to this:

```
public String [] getRecordData()

    {

    String[] str = null;

    int counter = 0;

    try

    {
        recordStore = RecordStore.openRecordStore("NameOfrecordStore", true);

        RecordEnumeration enumeration = recordStore.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);

        str = new String[recordStore.getNumRecords()];

        while(enumeration.hasNextElement()){

            try{

                str[counter] = (new String(enumeration.nextRecord()));
                counter ++;

            }catch (Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return str;
}
```

do same thing in getRecordData2()
add this code

```
recordStore2 = RecordStore.openRecordStore("NameOfrecordStore2", true);
```

before

```
RecordEnumeration enumeration = recordStore2.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);
```

remember when you use rms first open record store and than use it(read, change, delete,...).

// new answer to question
//replace this code with your according code;

//first replace this

```
addition.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
           String s =tf.getText();
           if(rb.isSelected()){
               if(s!=null && s.length() > 0){
                   try{
                       byte bytestream[] = s.getBytes()  ;
                       recordStore = RecordStore.openRecordStore("RecordStore1", true);
                       int i = recordStore.addRecord(bytestream, 0, bytestream.length);
                   }catch(Exception ex) {   
                       ex.toString();
                   }
               }
            }else if (rb2.isSelected()){
                if(s!=null && s.length() > 0){
                    try{
                        byte bytestream[] = s.getBytes()  ;
                        recordStore2 = RecordStore.openRecordStore("RecordStore2", true);
                        int i = recordStore2.addRecord(bytestream, 0, bytestream.length);
                    }catch(Exception ex) { }
                }

            }
        .....              
       }
   });
```

//second

```
  All.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {            
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
             ff.removeAll();
            try{
                com.sun.lwuit.Label l = new com.sun.lwuit.Label("First Team Goals") ;
                 ff.addComponent(l);
                 String [] record=  getRecordData();
                 List mylist = new List(new DefaultListModel(record));
                 ff.addComponent(mylist);

                 com.sun.lwuit.Label ll = new com.sun.lwuit.Label("Second Team Goals") ;
                 ff.addComponent(ll);
                 String [] record2=  getRecordData2();
                 List mylist2 =new List(new DefaultListModel(record2));
                 ff.addComponent(mylist2);
            }catch(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException e){}
            ff.show();                
         }
    });
```

its work well, its perfect!!.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem , please have you another suggestion?

Comment: OK my friend. 1- your code is very unreadable, 2- i say you first open recordstore and than work with it, 3- ....